# Speed difference between JAVA and JNI

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, native

I wanted to make my Android Studio code faster, so i translated some Java code to native C. Surprisingly, function written in c executes almost three time slower than java function. Also, i have applied ndk build optimization but that didn't change anything. My code:

1) Java function:

```
private int[] convolve(short signal[], short kernel[]) {
    int ret[] = new int[signal.length + kernel.length - 1];

    for (int n = 0; n < ret.length; n++){
        ret[n] = 0;

        int kmin = (n >= kernel.length - 1) ? n - (kernel.length - 1) : 0;
        int kmax = (n < signal.length - 1) ? n : signal.length - 1;

        for (int k = kmin; k <= kmax; k++) {
            ret[n] += signal[k] * kernel[n - k];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

2) C function:

```
int convolve_max(int16_t Signal[/* SignalLen */], int32_t SignalLen,
             int16_t Kernel[/* KernelLen */], int32_t KernelLen)
{
int32_t n;
double Result;
double MaxVal = 0;
int32_t MaxInd = 0;
double abs_sum = 0;

for (n = 0; n < SignalLen + KernelLen - 1; n++) {

    int32_t kmin, kmax, k;
    Result = 0;
    kmin = (n >= KernelLen - 1) ? n - (KernelLen - 1) : 0;
    kmax = (n < SignalLen - 1) ? n : SignalLen - 1;

    for (k = kmin; k <= kmax; k++) {
        Result += Signal[k] * Kernel[n - k];
    }

    Result = abs(Result);

    abs_sum += Result;

    if (Result > MaxVal) {
        MaxVal = Result;
        MaxInd = n;
    }

}

double trs = abs_sum / 200;
int offset = 0;

if (MaxVal > trs) {
    offset = MaxInd - 10 * 512;
}
else {
    offset = 51;
}
if (abs(offset) < 25) {
    return 1;
}

return 0;

}
```

I am aware that they are not completely same, but most important thing is nested loop, and that is the same.

Also, the look of my Gradle ndk build:

```
externalNativeBuild {
     ndkBuild {
         cppFlags "-std=c++11"
         arguments                                                                       "APP_STL=gnustl_static","NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9","APP_OPTIM=release","NDKDEBUG=0", "V=1"
         abiFilters "armeabi"
        }
    }`
```

So am I making some mistake, or there is some problem with jni?

Comment: The compiler probably does this, but you could make built-in variables for  (KernelLen - 1) and (SignalLen - 1) so they aren't in the loop.  This would trade memory for speed.... but it is a rather trivial improvement

Comment: I agree with you that lengths of array are not necessary, but that will not compensate such difference in speed.

Comment: The JIT may be doing a better job of vectorizing the Java version. I don't see any optimization flags for the C++ version, and the C compiler can't target NEON unless you tell it to, whereas JIT knows what the exact capabilities of the CPU it's running on are.